# Can I write e.preventDefault() using jQuery to all links in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering about that:

I have some links in my html file and to most of them I need to write in their click functions to not jump to the top of the page (which e.preventDefault() does that)ת I need to write that action aside from the functions that they actually do.

can I write something like that:

```
$('a').click(function(){e.preventDefault()})
```

Will it work? or will it create conflicts with the real functions if I will write like:

```
$('a').click(function(){e.preventDefault()});
$('a#goingToDoSomething').click(function(){console.log('just did it')})
```

I ask because I want to make my code better - but wasn't sure if that was the way..
thanks,
Alon

Comment: but if you have regular links to other pages or external links they will not work anymore because you disable them too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it will work, if you pass the [normalised event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to the callback function:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

No, there won't be any conflicts (conflicts? huh?). You can bind extra click handlers to your links and they will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, but not as efficient as:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Edit:**

```
$(document).on
```

will be even faster, but not tested it, should work though

requires jQuery 1.7+

Comment: You should add that it will work from jQuery 1.7+ version only

Comment: unfortunately I need to be compatible with v1.4.3

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine provided you pass the event object to the click handler. Try this

```
$('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault()})
```